# NGINX - Html Fallback Page Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a website (mostly static due to caches) and would like to redirect all not-found requests to index.html.

Everything is working fine on the first level of domain, it properly loads index.html, css and javascript.

But when user tries to access non-existent page on different levels, it still loads index.html but the CSS and Javascript returns 404.

Config I am using:

```
# index.html fallback
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Also beginning of server direction:

```
server {
    listen            443 ssl http2;
    listen            [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name       test.site;
    set               $base /var/www/test.site;
    root              $base/public;
```

Examples:

test.site/non-existent-page | **WORKS (index.html, css, javascript loads fine)**

- index.html loads correctly
- css,js files loads correctly from the root path (test.site/css/file.css or file.js)

test.site/level-1/non-existent-page | **DOESNT WORK (css, js files returns 404)**

- index.html loads correctly
- css,jss files returns 404 tries to load test.site/**level-1**/css/file.css or file.js

How could I fix it for higher levels of domain? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `index.html` file contains the URLs of the CSS and JS resource files. The problem is that you have used a relative URL which looks for the resource files in the subdirectory specified on the original request. Specify the URL of resource files with a leading `/`.

Comment: @RichardSmith That was the answer I needed, thank you very much!! Should I separate error pages or fallback for anything is fine especially for web crawlers? Thanks again!